# eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use App\Card;


class CardController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $cards = Card::all();
        return view('cards.index',compact('cards'));

    }

    public function show(Card $card)
    {
        $card->load('notes.user');

        return $card;

       // return view('cards.show',compact('card'));
    }
}
```

i'm new to laravel, and following along with a the laracast introduction tutorial. I'm attempting to eager load the user associated with the notes in my database but i keep getting the error, 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()'. i have no idea what the problem could be as i just started learning.
Below is the Card Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{

    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }

}
```

below is the Notes Class

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
    }
}
```

Below is the user Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your models as well, `Card` , `Note` and `User`

Comment: @KhalidDabjan i have added them

Comment: @KhalidDabjan thanks for pointing that out. i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the relationship for the user within the Notes class like below.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```